# What does "WM" mean in C++?

Tags: c++, winapi

I just had a question. Why do we use WM before everything like WM_COMMAND or WM_KEYDOWN or WM_INITDIALOG? What does WM mean? I'm making a game in C++ and I didn't know what WM was used for.

Comment: Windows Message?

Comment: It doesn't mean anything in C++. It has meaning in the Windows API.

Comment: @vld No. In case that was a genuine question. It's short for *"window message"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I can't say with any real *authority* but a shrewd 'guess' would be "**W**indow **M**essage."

Just before the definition of the first `WM_` macro, in the `WinUser.h` header file, this comment appears:

```cpp
/*
 * Window Messages
 */

#define WM_NULL                         0x0000
#define WM_CREATE                       0x0001
//...
```